# I'm not able to triangulate a regular point cloud

Tags: python, c++, opencv, qhull

I easily tessellated two parametric 3D surfaces (both convex surfaces).

These are the two tessellated parametric surfaces:

[image]

Now, my intention is to join both in a single solid. But I'm obtaining this:

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVjkx.png)

I'm using Qhull to create the Delaunay triangulation and it seems that works well for the 1st convex surface, but not for back surface. :(

This is my current code (parts taken from ZivS )

```
#include "Qhull.h"

using namespace orgQhull;

void myQhull::Qhull::runQhull3D(const pcl::PCLPointCloud2& pointCloud, const char* args)
{
    std::cout << "runQhull vertices" << std::endl;
    numVertices = 0;
    std::stringstream verticesSS;
    m_externalPoints = new PointCoordinates(3,"");  //3 = dimension
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pointCloud, *cloud);
    std::vector<double> allPoints;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < cloud->size(); i++) {
        allPoints.push_back(cloud->at(i).x);
        allPoints.push_back(cloud->at(i).y);
        allPoints.push_back(cloud->at(i).z);
        verticesSS << cloud->at(i).x << " " << cloud->at(i).y << " " << cloud->at(i).z << "\n";
        numVertices++;
    }
    vertices += verticesSS.str();


    m_externalPoints->append(allPoints); //convert to vector<double>
    runQhull(*m_externalPoints, args);
}


void myQhull::Qhull::runQhull(const PointCoordinates &points, const char *qhullCommand2)
{
    std::string triangles;
    std::stringstream ss;
    numSimplices = 0;
    int numFaces = 0;

    std::cout << numVertices << std::endl;
    std::cout << "runQhull facets" << std::endl;

    orgQhull::Qhull qHull(points.comment().c_str(), points.dimension(), points.count(), &*points.coordinates(), qhullCommand2);
    QhullFacetList facets = qHull.facetList();
    for (QhullFacetList::iterator it = facets.begin(); it != facets.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (!(*it).isGood()) continue;
        QhullFacet f = *it;
        QhullVertexSet vSet = f.vertices();
        auto coord = f.hyperplane().coordinates();

        numFaces = vSet.size();

        ss << numFaces;
        for (QhullVertexSet::iterator vIt = vSet.begin(); vIt != vSet.end(); ++vIt)
        {
            QhullVertex v = *vIt;
            QhullPoint p = v.point();
            double * coords = p.coordinates();
            ss <<  " " << p.id() << " ";
        }
        ss << "\n";
        numSimplices++;


    }

    simplices +=  ss.str();
    std::cout << numSimplices << std::endl;

}

void myQhull::Qhull::saveOff(std::string file)
{
    std::cout << "Saving qhull.off" << std::endl;
    std::ofstream offFile;
    offFile.open(file);

    offFile << "OFF\n";
    offFile << numVertices << " " << numSimplices << " 0";
    offFile << vertices;
    offFile << simplices;
    offFile.close();

}


void myQhull::Qhull::run(const pcl::PCLPointCloud2& pointCloud)
{
    Qhull qhull;
    qhull.runQhull3D(pointCloud, "Qt");
    qhull.saveOff("qhull.off");

}
```

Also, I used `greedy_projection` from OpenCV but without any success. It is  able only to perform the two surfaces tessellation without joining them.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. 
Adding "d" to `qhull.runQhull3D(pointCloud, "d Qt")` generates the correct Delaunay triangulation for upper and lower surface.
Therefore, as they are regular meshes I, manually, create the edge connecting vertices from the two surfaces.
Thank you.